# Pentaho / crossing files

Tags: csv, pentaho, kettle

Im trying to cross 2 different .csv files in order to have an output files indicating the new,changed,deleted and identical entries on the output file.
Im trying to do as explained here
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Merge+rows
Im using merge rows(diff) in order to try and achieve this but no matter what i try its not working, as key fields im only using the value of the row that doesnt update i.e an ID.
What i tried to do is using the same file for for both inputs,when i dont change anything  the flagfield value is "identical" for all rows,but then if i try and modifify ONE single value in ONE row in ONE of the files,i get all changed? and maybe 3 or 4 identical? any ideas why this is happening? I just can't figure it out,thanks in advanced.

Comment: Did you sort your input? That's usually the source of that problem. You must sort BOTH input streams to the Merge Rows (Diff) step, and in the same order, same case sensitivity, etc.

Comment: I was not,Im trying to use "sort rows" now but im getting an error during the merge ;(  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/268/r2lh.png/

Comment: Be sure you sort by the EXACT same keys, ascending/descending must match and case sensitivity must match. Also be sure the keys you use in the Merge Rows (Diff) step match EXACTLY the ones you're sorting on.

Comment: is that merge error when preview or running? if preview then run the transformation, you'll get a better stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Merge rows diff is the correct answer here.

If you're using a target database after the diff then you can pair it with "synchronise after merge" but in this case a text file output will do it.